# How does the collapse of a spherical cloud of point-masses look in the Newtonian framework?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, mass

Imagine a spherically symmetric cloud of point masses, without angular momentum, interacting by gravity only.

If we examine this process within a Newtonian framework, the particles accelerate towards the center where they collide and bounce back or pass the center without collision. If the distribution is perfectly symmetric, the center particles seem to bounce back coherently and meet the other infalling parts. Let's assume elastic collisions.

What happens to the cloud? Will it just end up as an expanding cloud again. So a time-reversed version of the collapse? Will there be some kind of matter waves be induced?

Comment: Your first paragraph is a bit odd. Point particles don't spaghettify, and they don't mysteriously turn into spacetime. Also, clouds of matter don't usually just collapse into black holes.

Comment: Regarding your Newtonian cloud, are the collisions perfectly elastic?

Comment: @PM2Ring well, the particles themselves don't. But if you fall in with them their distances in radial direction grow and the clocks tied on their backs show different times. They fall to infinity (I think). If time has passed a lot on the outside it looks like all matter has accumulated on the horizon but inside they are stretched out in space and time, all clocks showing differences but not more than the proper time it takes to fall towards the "hole" in space at infinity. Yes the collisions are elastic.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is basically a galaxy, and it does not collapse under its self gravity because it has angular momentum. Or it's a gas cloud which does collapse and is heated by the collapse until nuclear reactions occur. Or you are excluding collisions by your artificial constraint of only gravitational interactions, which is unphysical

Comment: Gerald mentions that collisions *do* occur, and he clarified in a comment that they are elastic. FWIW, dark matter (allegedly) behaves like that.